# Google Calendar Integration (Jolnir 6.1)

Tags: calendar, release-jolnir

I cannot for the life of me successfully sync my Google Calendar with the elementary Calendar app. I use 2FA so understand I will need to use an App Password. But, there are so many URLs in the Google Calendar settings and I am unsure where to put one of these when setting up the account in elementary OS. I am a little overwhelmed. If anyone can shed any light on the matter it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I just did it now. I also have 2FA.

1. Generate an app password for the calendar in [your google account](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords).
2. Open Maya (elementary Calendar) and add new google calendar from the cog menu (top right).
3. Fill in your gmail in the "user account" field and confirm.
4. A dialog pops up asking for password. Insert the app password created in step 1.

Done. After this I could see my events showing up in the callendar.